# Trouble with VBS InStr - using a nested InStr as the optional start argument

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Good morn all...I need some help porting a function from VBA to VBS

Here is an example of the data set my question is based on.

```
USA_66544_File.doc
RUS_3465_File.txt
```

I used the function to extract the string of numbers between the two underscores. In case it matters, i started off by breaking the string into segments, based on the underscore, then patched this together to isolate just the string i wanted.

```
=MID(A5,FIND("_",A5)+1,FIND("_",A5,FIND("_",A5)+1)-FIND("_",A5)-1) '##original working in Excel
```

The output from the above would be 66544 and 3465 respectively.

I then needed to port this function to VBS.  MID is ok, but FIND changes to InStr.  Also, my cell reference (A5) changes to a 2D array of size array(1,7)

```
MID(array(0,x),InStr(array(0,x),"_")+1,InStr(InStr(array(0,x),"_")+1),array(0,x),"_")'-(Instr(array(0,x),"_")-1)
```

I am getting the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Here is what i think i am doing. MID accepts three arguments, with the last being optional.

```
MID(string, start, [# of char to return]
```

1. string = array(0,x)
2. start = InStr(array(0,x),"_")+1 (this should find an underscore,
   then return the next number)
3. length =
   Instr(Instr(array(0,x),"*"),array(0,x),"*")-Instr(array(0,x),"_")-1

So to bring it all together in case it matters, in my 2D array, the first dimension will contain the full string

```
USA_66544_File.doc
RUS_3465_File.txt
```

And the second, the output from the function

```
66544
3465
```

I anyone can help me make sense of this, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thanks,
Herb

Comment: Why not: `Split(array(0,x), "_")(1)`

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is using Split():

```
>> Dim array(0,0)
>> array(0,0) = "USA_66544_File.doc"
>> WScript.Echo array(0,0), Split(array(0,0), "_")(1)
>>
USA_66544_File.doc 66544
```

I used the variable name `array` in this demo, because I want to make sure that re/mis-using the name of the [Array()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxhtazh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function does not throw an error. Still choosing a better name is advisable.

If you want to use Mid() and Instr(), do it step by step:

```
>> s = "USA_66544_File.doc"
>> f = InStr(1, s, "_") + 1
>> t = InStr(f, s, "_")
>> l = t - f
>> WScript.Echo Mid(s, f, l)
>>
66544
```

After having done it correctly, optimizing is easy:

```
>> s = "USA_66544_File.doc"
>> f = InStr(1, s, "_") + 1
>> WScript.Echo Mid(s, f, InStr(f, s, "_") - f)
>>
66544
```

Inlining f (i.e. repeating the expression) would surely not be an optimization, especially if you consider the need to add some error checks.